# Can display dialogue with function, but cannot set variable with function

Tags: variables, applescript

I want to take the return value of the function getProjectTag().

```
tell application "TaskPaper"
    tell front document
        repeat with the_entry in entries
            -- For each entry, get the data from TaskPaper

            tell the_entry
                set project_name to getProjectTag(the_entry)
```

I get the error:

> TaskPaper got an error: item 26 of every entry of document 1 doesn’t
>   understand the getProjectTag message." number -1708 from item 26 of every entry of document 1

However, when I replace:

```
set project_name to getProjectTag(the_entry)
```

with:

```
display dialogue my getProjectTag(the_entry)
```

it shows me a dialogue of the correct return value -- so the function is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me:

```
set project_name to my getProjectTag(the_entry)
```

fixes the problem.

I wasn't aware of what *my* did.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Calling a subroutine from a `tell` block/statement without the word `my` suggests that the subroutine is a command related to whatever the `tell` block/statement is addressing. Telling `me` to `getProjectTag(the_entry)` looks **everywhere** in the script, not just whatever is being addressed.